# how to change Material Icon with onPress or onClick event?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
const [icon,setIcon]=useState('star-outline')

  const handlePress=()=>
  {
        setIcon("star")
  }
...........

<MaterialCommunityIcons
          name={icon}
          size={24}
          color="black"
          onPress={handlePress(icon)}
        />

..............
```

I tried some solutions but it doesn't work. I have tried to directly pass it as well without hooks but it doesnt work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [selected,setSelected]=useStat(false)
const [icon,setIcon]=useState('star-outline')//
   const handlePress=()=>
    {
      setIcon("star")
    }
    ...........

    <MaterialCommunityIcons
      name={selected?'star-outline':'star-filled'}
      size={24}
      color="black"
      onPress={handlePress(icon)}
    />
```

i have changde your code, you can have a state called selected, and on the basis of this state you can change the name of the icon. and i think this will done .